# Flutter recipe app with API does not go to next screen and doesn't run on mobile debugging

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, browser

I have this problem where i have already coded the majority of my application which is a recipe app that has a calorie calculator and an API integration in which i followed a youtube tutorial on. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3CIMZSAaIk&ab_channel=MarcusNg
When i try to run it on my pc using chrome and it gives me an error in the browser_client.dart

I expected the app to run flawlessly since it is from an online tutorial but it shows me an error here. [it highlights the error in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niBM7.jpg) I cannot get it to run properly and to switch over to the next screen. i tried some fixes suggested by chatGPT but nothing works. Is it possibly a browser thing? the browser_client.dart is nowhere to be found in my lib folder so i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.